# how can I fix reverse command managment between client - server?

Tags: python

I am building a remote managment toolkit in order to control my machine raspberry pi remotely with python , but however my code is kind of reverse. instead of sending commands , I am getting controlled by raspberry pi

controller

```
import socketserver
from datetime import datetime
import json, os

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print('{} - {} CONNECTED.'.format(datetime.now(), self.client_address))
        while True:
            self.request.send(bytes(os.popen(str(self.request.recv(1024),encoding='utf-8')).read(),encoding='utf-8'))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    server = socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()
```

client

```
import socket
import json

client = socket.socket()
client.connect(('localhost',9999))

while True:
    msg = input(">>: ").strip()
    client.send(msg.encode("UTF-8"))

    data = client.recv(1024) #  Receiving 1024 bytes

    if not data == b'successful':
        print('resending')
    print(data)

client.close()
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are running the server script on the pi and the client script on your own machine, right?

Comment: exactly. my server.py is my the controler script from all my `pi` machines so it will perform management commands , and other things where I need to do it via python and this way. basically server is on my machine , and client on pi

Comment: Why are you using ```localhost``` in  your client script?

Comment: @ewong just development before upload the codes to pi

Comment: Then I'm a bit confused.  If you're running the server and client script on the same machine,  wouldn't any commands you send on your client be executed on your client system?  Did I miss something?  Also, in the server script, you should be using the IP of your PI.

Comment: sure, but the output from what server gives it should be in client.py , and it gives me the reverse client.py acts as a connector , but it gives commands to server where it should be `cmd> ps` < on server , and client > output from server

Comment: Please include the commands and results in your post.